# How to access to the Raspberry pi files using a python gui running on windows?

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I am developping an application in which i have to establish an ethernet connection between raspberry pi and a windows pc. On my pc i want to develop a python program (gui) that can not only import files from the raspberry pi, but also read those files and modify them. I don't want to use any soft or program already existing. So what is the best solution: sockets, or ssh? or there is an other choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba, FTP/SFTP, or also (if doable on windows) SSHFS. If you want your own implementation then for example you could use a REST API (web app) running on PI and allowing file operations in some folders (create, modify, delete, get, list...). You could also think about using Git and git pulling/pushing between each other :)